# How to make terminal transparent while still having its own background image?

Tags: command-line, desktop-background

Is there a way to give terminal specific background image and make it 50% transparent at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about Gnome Terminal, select your background image and adjust below transparency slider - it's in same tab in same preferences dialog

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm on gnome shell. But I still cant make it transparent. If background image is chosen, then slider below adjusts transparent between chosen color and background, not the window it self.

Comment: Then make your background image transparent to your liking with some image editor (PNG + Alpha) and set above mentioned slider to 0 (None)

Answer (score 1):

The options for gnome terminal do not allow you to set a transparency mask for a background image.

You can either choose from a solid color background, a background image where you can set the opacity shade of that image or transparent background where you can set the level of transparency for the terminal's selected background color.

If you select a image as a background you wont be able to see tru that image.

What you can do is create an image in a format that allows transparency (ie png) and set that image as your background for the terminal.

---

#### Step by step

I have started with this image called `ubuntu-backgrounds7.jpg`

[image]

I have open it with Gimp and set the transparency of it to 75% and saved it as `ubuntu-backgrounds7.png` in a folder inside my home.

I then go to *Edit* > *Profile Preferences* > *Background* and set the image I have just created as the selected background for my terminal.

[image]

You can then adjust the opacity for the background with the slider to get the desired shade on your background.

[image]

Comment: But user that asked this question did not wanted color mask which is applied if simply using slider, as you can see from your example images. Making transparency slider to 0 (zero) you can use your custom image transparency without applied mask (which is chosen by the color set as terminal background)

Comment: @zetah The answer clearly says he can adjust that with the slider. I rest complete ;)

Comment: @zetah Yours is the correct answer this is just a extra. Tell you what, make a small guide as I did (you can even copy mine I dont care) and I will delete this. (drop a comment if you do it) I mean you do have the answer in your comments ;)

Comment: I was just commenting as I didn't know if you read the comments, that user did not wanted color mask applied (kinda purple on your example). Feel free to edit my answer and extend it as Jorge already did

Comment: @zetah I cannot find reference to any part of the question that mentions "no shade" in it, only "50% transparent" and since this is only an example made for [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86801/can-i-set-different-transparent-backgrounds-for-terminal) I will keep it this way.