# Can I set different Transparent backgrounds for Terminal?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make terminal transparent while still having its own background image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78518/how-to-make-terminal-transparent-while-still-having-its-own-background-image)

I want Transparent backgrounds in Terminal but different background..

Answer (score 2):

The options for gnome terminal do not allow you to set a transparency mask for a background image.

You can either choose from a solid color background, a background image where you can set the opacity shade of that image or transparent background image where you can set the level of transparency for the background.

If you select a image as a background you wont be able to see tru that image.

What you can do is create an image in a format that allows transparency (ie png) and set that image as your background for the terminal.

---

#### Step by step

I have started with this image called `ubuntu-backgrounds7.jpg`

[image]

I have open it with Gimp and set the transparency of it to 75% and saved it as `ubuntu-backgrounds7.png` in a folder inside my home.

I then go to *Edit* > *Profile Preferences* > *Background* and set the image I have just created as the selected background for my terminal.

[image]

You can then adjust the opacity for the background with the slider to get the desired shade on your background.

[image]

Comment: Thank You Very Much!!! .Transparent Default wallpaper ~/firefox.....png ....But I want different add wallpaper and make Transparent . I want to change.. – erkan şentürk just now edit